# Kernel trick: computationally inexpensive

Tags: kernel-trick

I am reading [this post](http://www.chioka.in/explain-to-me-what-is-the-kernel-trick/) about the kernel trick. The author claims that a calculation of a dot product of two vectors will need 100.000.000 multiplications given that both vectors are of a dimension (10000 x 1).

I am not sure I understand this claim. The dot product of two vectors v1= (v1,v2) and c=(c1,c2) is just v1*c1+v2*c2, and there are only 2 multiplications needed, which means that if our vectors would be of dim (10000 x 1) one would need 10.000 multiplications and not more.

Am I mistaken somewhere?

Comment: You are correct about the dot product, but your reference misuses this term. Evidently it means *matrix product,* which in this instance implements what is sometimes called the *outer product.*  It calls for every component of one vector to be multiplied by every component of the other.